# best way to print a Grid in a GridLayout of n*m

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I want a **n*m grid** with border and color for each cell like shown in the image.

For this i am currently using the **GridLayout of n*m size** and inside it i am using the ImageView to print the specific color in each cell,  also for the blank cell i am using the ImageView (Image with only borders rest blank).

So this is making performance issue because of high number of Views .

Is there a way which can so the following things which out using a View for each cell?

**1. Grid View with some border for each cell(so it should look like grid)**

**2. for any random cell i have to assign the color to it when it was clicked.**

**3. each cell should tell its row and column number to me .**

[image]

Comment: Use RecyclerView with GridlayoutManager.

Comment: try to use a simple View with background color instead of ImageView.